# DAX SWITCH multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

```
Color no Stock = SWITCH(
     TRUE()
     ,[Bestand] < 0 && [Bestand] > -[ZUS], "#f44242"
     ,[Bestand] < -[ZUS], "#8800ff"
 )
```

Hi,

i want to use the switch function, to display the numbers in the matrix in a certain font color.

- If  number < 0 -> number should be red.
- Else If number < - ZUS (in this example 1500) -> number should be purple.

[image]

Unfortanely everything below 0 is purple

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: I'm not able to share this one. But nonetheless, I got the same issue with a KPI card (conditional formatting did also not work properly). But the same measure for a table worked. So I'm kinda thinking there is a issue with the matrix visual?

Comment: There is no issue with the matrix - your code is incorrect but it is difficult to diagnose without seeing all the pieces. Can you create a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: You should NEVER post your company issues on StackOverflow (Are you working on the controlling of a German company that deals with office supplies?) , but create a minimal, reproducible example instead, so that other can either help you or learn from the solution. Now we have the situation that your problem isn't reproducible and you are not able to reveal further details. Very unsatisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not reproducible. With

```
Color no Stock = SWITCH(
     TRUE(),
     SUM('Table'[Amount]) < 0 && SUM('Table'[Amount]) > -1500, "#f44242",
     SUM('Table'[Amount]) < - 1500, "#8800ff"
 )
```

I get:

[image]

Works like expected.

Comment: i am using a measure to calculate the number which the color should turn purple.

ZUS = CALCULATE(SUM(CA_MD04_ALL_REQUIREMENT[Open Qty]),CA_MD04_ALL_REQUIREMENT[Requirement Type] = "ZUS")

The number will be correctly displayed (in this example 1500). But while using the color measure, it does not work

Comment: oh sry it is. thank you very much